# Android - Best way to use git submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

Let me suppose a project **App** with 4 external modules: **ModA**, **ModB**, **ModC** and **ModD** that could be used by another projects in a re-usable way.

The idea behind the project is to link the project to internal git submodules into a folder named "modules" .

For example, the related settings.gradle could be:

```
include ':app'
include ':modules:ModA'
include ':modules:ModB'
include ':modules:ModC'
include ':modules:ModD'
```

and all works fine with this .gitmodules file:

```
[submodule "modules/ModA"]
    path = modules/ModA
    url = ssh://git@bitbucket.org/repo/ModA.git
[submodule "modules/ModB"]
    path = modules/ModB
    url = ssh://git@bitbucket.org/repo/ModB.git
[submodule "modules/ModC"]
    path = modules/ModC
    url = ssh://git@bitbucket.org/repo/ModC.git
[submodule "modules/ModD"]
    path = modules/ModD
    url = ssh://git@bitbucket.org/repo/ModD.git
```

Now, suppose that the ModA has dependencies with ModC and ModD, what is the best way to connect them? Add a sub-sub-module to ModA with ModC and ModD or deploy artifacts of ModC and ModD on maven and use them as dependencies?

### Module's Tree

- App

  - ModA

    - ModC
    - ModD
  - ModB
  - ModC
  - ModD

### The question

If the App needs changes to ModC, the changes affects only the modules/ModC into App modules directory. The ModA (that has ModC like a module) doesn't see any changes.

Do you have any ideas? How can I handle a change one time?

I've a bit of confusion about this argument.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1) Using maven artifacts is the way to go here.
To simplify local development you may use Gradle Composite Builds (since Gradle 3.1) https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html to replace artifact dependencies by a build that has the projects next to each other locally.

According to the Gradle Documentation this should replace the artifact dependency with a project dependency and greatly simplify your development.

Option 2) git submodules:
Assuming a final directory structure like:

```
App/{build.gradle,settings.gradle}
App/modules/ModA/{build.gradle,settings.gradle}
App/modules/ModA/modules/ModC/
App/modules/ModC/{build.gradle,settings.gradle}
```

`App/build.gradle`: reference modules simply like normal projects

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':ModA')
    compile project(':ModC')
}
```

`App/settings.gradle`: include the subprojects like:

```
include 'ModA'
project(':ModA').projectDir = new File('modules/ModA')
include 'ModC'
project(':ModC').projectDir = new File('modules/ModC')
```

`App/modules/ModA/build.gradle` normal project references just like above

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':ModC')
}
```

`App/modules/ModA/settings.gradle` the important part here is to use the same project name as above

```
include 'ModC'
project(':ModC').projectDir = new File('modules/ModC')
```

In the directory structure you notice `App/modules/ModA/modules/ModC/` which contains an unused copy of the source of ModC that is assuming that ModA would also use submodules to manage dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a way to manage them like git submodules?